# How do I integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx$?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

How do I integrate 
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}\;\mathrm{d}x\;?$$
I'm sure that there's a way to do this with the Gamma function, but I just don't see it..

Comment: Integrate by parts works, with $u = x, dv = xe^{-x^{2}/2}$. You will then need to solve the integral $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-x^{2}/2} dx$$ which can be done by squaring the integral and using polar coordinates.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral

Comment: Don't you see a connection between $x^re^{-x}$ and $x^se^{-x^2/2}$ ? Serious ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust well no need to be so annoying about it

Comment: @ant: no annoyance intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* use the Gamma function, though in my opinion, you're better off using integration by parts alongside the integration of the Gaussian. Anyway, here's a solution with the Gamma function in use.

$$2\int\limits_0^{\infty}x^2e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}\ dx $$

Let $u=\frac12x^2$ such that $du =  x dx = \sqrt{2u}dx$. Then,

$$4\int\limits_0^{\infty}u e^{-u}\ \frac{du}{\sqrt{2u}} = \frac{4}{\sqrt2}\int\limits_0^{\infty}u^{1/2} e^{-u}\ du = \frac{4}{\sqrt2}\Gamma(3/2) = \frac{4}{\sqrt2}\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2} = \sqrt{2\pi}$$

Answer (score 3):

This resembles the second order moment of a standard normal distribution, sans the normalizing constant. So if we let $X \sim N(0,1)$ then
\begin{align}
1 = EX^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}x^2e^{-x^2/2}\mathrm{d}x.
\end{align}

Comment: Good to recognize this, but actually this is not an answer to the question ("how do I integrate?") of the OP.

Comment: Yeah, it's more of a dirty trick but I couldn't help. As long as it's not Calculus 101 where OP's restricted to good ol' techniques of integration such as integration by parts I think this method is still acceptable.

Comment: If you would not have given this answer, then I would :). Simply too hard to resist the temptation.

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2/2}dx=\sqrt{2\pi}\alpha^{-1/2},$$ differentiation under the integral sign with respect to $-\alpha/2$ gives $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 e^{-\alpha x^2/2}dx=\sqrt{2\pi}\alpha^{-3/2}.$$ Substituting $\alpha=1$ gives $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 e^{-x^2/2}dx=\sqrt{2\pi}.$$

Answer (score 0):

To go back to known integrals, start using $x=y\sqrt 2$. This gives $$\int x^2e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,dx=2\sqrt 2\int y^2e^{-y^2}\,dy$$ Now $$\int y^2e^{-y^2}\,dy=\int y y e^{-y^2}dy=-\frac 12\int y(-2y)e^{-y^2}dy$$ which makes clear the integration by parts $$u=y\qquad v'=-2ye^{-y^2}dy\qquad u'=dy\qquad v=e^{-y^2}$$ So $$\int y^2 e^{-y^2}dy=-\frac 12\Big(ye^{-y^2}-\int e^{-y^2}dy\Big)$$

I am sure that you can take from here.